# Opencart: Disabled product still shows in bestseller

Tags: module, opencart, product

Not really sure why this is, but when I disable a product in the admin, it is still showing in the bestseller module. It has been removed everywhere else. There is no product page, there is no listing in any category, and you can not search for it anymore.

Unfortunately the bestseller module isn't on board with the rest of the system. The image, title, and button are still all "active" for the disabled product. Clicking does bring you to a 404 page, but it is strange (And crazy annoying) that a disabled product is still used.

I can't figure the thing out, any ideas on this?

*And why is a bestseller disabled: Supplier stopped supplying them. working with v1.5.5.1 if it matters.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem, disabled products are removed from bestseller section (v.1.5.5.1). Check function getBestSellerProducts in product.php (ModelCatalogProduct), and query inside it, but... i guess that nothing is changed there... Also, check cache file for bestseller products - should be removed or empty, after admin disable products...

Comment: Damn it... cache..... thanks @nevermind

Comment: Ah just seen your comment. +1 nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely culprit is going to be a cache file that needs deleting. Open `/system/cache/` and find a file starting `product.bestseller` and delete it. This should fix it. If this doesn't fix it, then it's going to be a modification causing this (vQmod most probably)

Comment: Yup, nevermind beat you to the punch, but thanks for always checking my opencart problems... Vqmod manager takes care of it... some days...